# How to solve Observable<Observable<{...}>[ ]> to Observable<{...}[ ]>?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to combine two observable objects to one observable, so I can use information from both of these objects. The observable objects are both documents from two different collections in a NoSQL database (a Cloud Firestore database). Both collections shares a field with the same value (uid and partnerID). I first created a query to get the first observable object and this query returns an `Observable<{Object1}[]>`. Know if I try to add code to get the second observable object and combine it with the existing one, I get an `Observable<Observable<{Object1 merged with Object2}>[]>`.

How can I make sure that the generated observable is a array consisting of objects that are a combination of these two objects that I extract from the database?

My goal is to use the combined observable object in my Angular project. I'm trying to achieve this with rxjs operators.

This is the function in my service without the second observable object:

```
queryMatches(fieldNameOfRole, boolValueOfAccepted) {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        return this.angularFirestore
          .collection('matches', ref => ref.where(fieldNameOfRole, '==', user ? user.uid : '')
            .where('accepted', '==', boolValueOfAccepted))
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              return actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Match;
                const matchId = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { matchId, ...data };
              });
            })
          );
      })
    );
  }
```

This produces the following return:

```
(method) MatchStoreService.queryMatches(fieldNameOfRole: any, boolValueOfAccepted: any): Observable<{
    initiatorID: string;
    partnerID: string;
    matchedOffer: string;
    accepted: boolean;
    id: string;
}[]>
```

And this is how I tried to combine it with the second observable object:

```
queryMatches(fieldNameOfRole, boolValueOfAccepted) {
    return this.authService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        return this.angularFirestore
          .collection('matches', ref => ref.where(fieldNameOfRole, '==', user ? user.uid : '')
            .where('accepted', '==', boolValueOfAccepted))
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              return actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Match;
                const matchId = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { matchId, ...data };
              });
            })
          );
      }),
      map(matches => {
        return matches.map(match => {
          return this.userStoreService.getUserById(match.partnerID).pipe(
            map(user => {
              return { ...match, ...user };
            })
          );
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

This produces the following return:

```
(method) MatchStoreService.queryMatches(fieldNameOfRole: any, boolValueOfAccepted: any): Observable<Observable<{
    uid: string;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
    sex: string;
    city: string;
    activities: string[];
    offers: string[];
    mail?: string;
    ... 4 more ...;
    matchId: string;
}>[]>
```

**UPDATE**

How I implemented getUserById():

```
getUserById(uid) {
    return this.angularFirestore
    .collection<any>(`users`)
    .doc<User>(uid).valueChanges();
   }
```

Comment: looks like you need to use some flattening operators, like [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) instead of `map` in order to have stream of values instead of steam of observables

Comment: I think so too, but where should I use witch one? I tried it in different combinations, but nothing worked.

Comment: If you return Observable from callback of a `map` - you should use `mergeMap` (work for array too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use forkJoin operator like this

```
 map(matches => {
        return combineLatest(matches.map(match => {
          return this.userStoreService.getUserById(match.partnerID).pipe(
            map(user => {
              return { ...match, ...user };
            })
          );
        }));
      })
```

Comment: I changed it like you said, but had to change the first map to switchMap and then the return changed to `Observable<{Object1}[]> `. But for a reason, if I call subscribe() on the method, I don't get any results.

Comment: till the last line, all my console.log()'s are working and giving my even the combined object back, but if I try to subscribe() to it, it doesn't gave me any result. Not even my console.log()'s in the subscribe() works

Comment: @ConstantinBeer does `this.userStoreService.getUserById` complete? All Observables in `forkJoin` have to complete.

Comment: @fridoo I added the implementation of `this.userStoreService.getUserById`. My console.log() of `user` gave me the information of the user document. So I think it's complete or is there something else to do?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer, forkJoin waits for all sources to complete before emitting the value, however in getUserById valueChanges() is returned. because of that - it never completes. If you want to get all the updates provided  by those streams replace `forkJoin` in my answer with `combineLatest`. If you want only one value, than either make your getUserById method return one value or use `zip(observables).pipe(first())`

Comment: Thank you a lot. Know it works and I also understand observables a bit more. If you would update your answer (`forkJoin` to  ´combineLatest´ ) I would mark it as the correct answer. Also I had to use `switchMap` instead of ´map´, like I mentioned before.